# Singleton only in plus'ed dagger graph

Tags: android, dagger

I have a [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) object graph that is able to produce instances of `MyClass` implicitly, as the constructor of `MyClass` is annotated with `@Inject`.

I also have a module that I `plus` onto my existing graph. My goal is for the plus'ed graph, and only for the plus'ed graph, to treat `MyClass` as a singleton and to always return the same instance.

How can I best achieve that with minimal boilerplate code, i.e. without

a) Constructing the instances myself in the plus'ed-on module by writing a `@Provides @Singleton` method, declaring all the dependencies of `MyClass`:

```
@Module public class Submodule {
  @Provides @Singleton MyClass provideMyClass(DepA depA, DepB depB) {
    return new MyClass(depA, depB);
  }
}
```

b) Extracting an interface from `MyClass` and again writing provider methods:

```
@Module public class Submodule {
  @Provides @Singleton IMyClass provideMyClass(MyClassImpl myClass) {
    return myClass;
  }
}
```

My concrete use case is that of an Android app, where an `Activity` instance depends on a presenter that should also be injected in fragments of the activity. Because several instances of the same `Activity` can exist, I can't declare `MyClass` a singleton globally.

I guess in the end, the question boils down to how one can write something like this, without the dependency cycle:

```
@Provides @Singleton public MyClass provideMyClass(MyClass m) { return m; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. You'll have to provide the `@Singleton` annotation *somewhere*.
Legal places for this are directly above the class declaration, or in a method annotated with `@Provides`.

With these two restrictions in mind, you've already proposed all possible solutions: The class declaration is not helpful since it should only be a singleton in the plus'ed graph, and the `@Provides` methods can only be implemented like you did.

---

The only thing I can think of that might be able to do this, is to supply your original `ObjectGraph` into your `Submodule`'s constructor, and use `ObjectGraph.get(MyClass.class)` to return in your `provideMyClass` method. The con of course is that any overridden dependencies in your submodule are not used when creating the `MyClass` instance.

I think this method generates way too much overhead and introduces possible (future) bugs in comparison to your suggested methods.

Comment: One more idea I had that I'm bouncing off you, since you wrote the only reply :) I'm currently pondering whether it would be horrible or beautiful to have the plus'ed on module itself declare some dependencies (e.g. the presenter) and let the mother-graph instantiate or inject that module?

Comment: @HannesStruß I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps you could start a new question where you can provide some example code?

Comment: something like this: https://gist.github.com/hannesstruss/827dad670971456adb8b But I'm not really convinced it's even worth consideration and thus its own question. I tried it and it works, but I think variant a) from my original question is probably better in terms of the principle of least surprise.